# ¿Cómo poner contraseña en un script sh automáticamente?

Tags: shell-script

Tengo la siguiente arquitectura: Un servidor linux y 10 host en diferentes ip, las cuales desconozco.

Objetivo: Desde el servidor hacer un for, recorrer todas las IPs y dejar un log. En el caso que encuentre una IP arriba, hará una consulta, para recoger un cat del host y escribirlo en log.
He aquí el problema: al hacer la pregunta al host, solicita la contraseña y yo deseo automatizar este paso, por ejemplo solicitar la contraseña al inicio del script y guardarla en una variable, pero no sé automatizar este paso. Debo recalcar que no puedo instalar nada en el servidor, como ssh o expect. Os dejo el código para explicarme mejor.

```
# ver 1.0
#!/bin/bash
read -p "IP de inicio : " ip_star
read -p "IP de fin : " ip_end
# ip_star="40"
# ip_end="50"
function f_comprobar_log(){
    imhere=$(pwd)
    if [[ $imhere"/XXXXX.log" ]]; then
    rm $imhere"/XXXXXX.log"
    fi
}
function f_escribe_fecha(){
    DIA=`date +"%d/%m/%Y"`
    HORA=`date +"%H:%M"`
    fechayhora= echo $DIA $HORA
    return $fechayhora
}
function f_hora(){
    HORA=`date +"%H:%M"`
}
function f_segundos(){
    SEGUNDOS=`date +"%S"`
}
function f_escribe_log () {
    log="$1"
    echo "$log" >> XXXX.log
}
function f_ping_a_IP () {
    ip="$1"
    if [ ! -z "$ip" ] ; then
        respuesta_ping=$(ping -c1 -w1 $ip |grep "100% packet loss")
        if [ ! -z "$respuesta_ping" ]; then
            respuesta_ping=$(echo -e "\e[0;31mABAJO\e[0m")
        else
            respuesta_ping=$(echo -e "\e[1;32mARRIBA\e[0m")
            echo "host numero : "$i >> /tmp/XXXX.log
            ZZZ=$(ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=1 root@$ipdeconexion cat /etc/motd >> /tmp/XXXX.log)
        fi
    else 
        respuesta_ping="Empty"
    fi
}
f_escribe_log "#################### "`echo $0`" ####################"
f_escribe_log "`f_escribe_fecha`"

#segmento_conexion=$(hostname -i | cut -d' ' -f'2'| cut -d'.' -f'1-3')
segmento_conexion=$(ip r |grep XX |cut -d' ' -f'9'| cut -d'.' -f'1-3')
i=$ip_star
for i in $(seq $ip_star $ip_end)
do
    ipdeconexion=$(echo "$segmento_conexion.$i")
    f_ping_a_IP $ipdeconexion
    f_hora
    f_segundos
    f_escribe_log "$HORA:$SEGUNDOS - $ipdeconexion - $respuesta_ping"
done
```

Comment: Me ha pasado lo mismo de tener esas restricciones, la única forma que encontré fue usando claves pública-privada generadas con `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro interes, me habeis ayudado mucho para dilucidar el problema.

Comment: he encontrado una posible solución en este link: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/158637/como-enviar-la-contrasena-de-sudo-en-un-shell-shellscriptshell

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que estás buscando automatizar la recopilación de logs de los hosts y lidiar con la autenticación SSH sin la posibilidad de instalar software adicional. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que automatizar el ingreso de contraseñas en un script puede ser inseguro y no es una práctica recomendada desde el punto de vista de la seguridad.

Dicho esto, es posible lograr lo que deseas utilizando claves SSH sin contraseña y utilizando el control de flujo y la programación del shell para interactuar con los hosts a través de SSH sin necesidad de ingresar la contraseña manualmente. A continuación, te proporciono una descripción general de cómo podrías abordar esto:

1. **Configurar SSH Key-Based Authentication**: En cada uno de los hosts, configura la autenticación basada en claves SSH para el usuario que usarás para recopilar los logs. Esto implica generar un par de claves SSH (pública y privada) y agregar la clave pública en el archivo `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` en el host remoto.
2. **Utilizar sshpass (opción menos segura, se necesita instalar)**: En el escenario en el que no puedas usar SSH Key-Based Authentication y no puedas instalar nada en el servidor, podrías utilizar la herramienta `sshpass`. Sin embargo, esto implica instalar `sshpass` y pasar la contraseña directamente en el comando SSH, lo cual es menos seguro.
3. **Usar Expect (opción menos segura, se necesita instalar)**: Similar a `sshpass`, podrías utilizar el programa `expect` para automatizar la interacción con el proceso SSH, enviando la contraseña cuando sea solicitada.

Por razones de seguridad, la mejor opción sigue siendo configurar autenticación basada en claves SSH, pero si no puedes hacerlo, las otras opciones podrían ayudarte a lograr tu objetivo, aunque con ciertas limitaciones en términos de seguridad.

Comment: Sabes que el uso de IA para contestar preguntas esta prohibido, no?

Comment: Si, lo sé, pero no uso IA, todas las preguntas que repondo es porque tengo conocimientos de ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro interes, me habeis ayudado mucho para dilucidar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada, muchas gracias a todos por el interés en colaborar altruistamente con vuestro conocimiento a otros colegas.
Efectivamente, como dice @Johnny sin instalar nada, es imposible hacerlo, ya que una parte de la seguridad de Linux está basado en esto.
Como solución provisional por ahora, al ejecutar el sh, voy poniendo la contraseña.
El próximo paso será utilizar certificados de clave pública y privada para la conexión.
Cuando termine el código si os interesa os lo puedo compartir.
Muchas gracias a todos por vuestro tiempo y atención

Comment: De hecho que para que tu respuesta sea completa, es mejor que compartas explícitamente cómo resolviste tu problema, así ayudás a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema más adelante. Luego de [edit] tu respuesta (y de eliminar el texto duplicado, por cierto), no olvides [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Comment: Estimada @padaleiana, he editado el mensaje, ya que sin querer había pegado dos veces el mismo texto, pero la solución provisional que tengo es ir escribiendo la contraseña.